# Whatever happened to Bitcoin miners mining additional coins in combination with Bitcoin mining like pre-2015?

Tags: mining-pools, mining-reward, miner-configuration, namecoin, merged-mining

Back in the early days of Bitcoin mining, many people were dual mining namecoin with bitcoin and some other coins. Why don't we hear anymore of this dual mining functionality in 2021+?

What were some of the other coins being dual mined with BTC? I just remember namecoin.

Comment: By dual-mining you mean merged mining?

Comment: Related: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/61316/5406

Comment: I edited under the assumption that merged mining was meant.

Answer (score -1):

Mining is getting harder and harder every 2016 blocks (difficulty adjustment). Good mining hardware you see today is dedicated to bitcoin only. Back in the days it was profitable to mine on a pc but today you will see more than the mined bitcoin back on your electricity bill.

Comment: Downvoted, this isn't the reason. Namecoin is merge-mined with Bitcoin, so all the same hardware can be used.